# Call a process asynchronously via WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I am in a scenario wherein I need to call an exe process via an API endpoint (fire and forget). However, the exe that I will call is a long running one but I need to wait for it to finish to execute further codes. This will happen in the background and the client shouldn't really wait for it. When I'm trying the code below, the call is waiting for the exe process to finish. I've also tried making the method "async" but still same result.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<bool> ToggleCarWeaverService(string command)
    {
        try
        {
            var fileName = @"SomeExe.exe";
            await _service.RunProcessAsync(command, fileName);
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }


    public Task<int> RunProcessAsync(string command, string fileName)
    {
        // Use ProcessStartInfo class
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            UseShellExecute = true,
            FileName = fileName,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            Arguments = command
        };

        try
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = startInfo,
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };

            process.Exited += (sender, args) =>
            {
                tcs.SetResult(process.ExitCode);
                //Do more code
                process.Dispose();

            };

            process.Start();

            return tcs.Task;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log error.
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: then do not await.

Comment: @but will the part where //Do more code still be called upon exit of the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not await the async task.

Use `Task.Run` to wrap and continue

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult ToggleCarWeaverService(string command) {
    Task.Run(async () => {
        var fileName = @"SomeExe.exe";
        await _service.RunProcessAsync(command, fileName);
        //...other code after process finish
    });
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: yeah this worked, but could you explain further what's Task.Run is doing?

Comment: @kempyyyy All it is doing is wrapping a func (which in this case is everything inside the `{}`) inside a task which you can think of as a seperate thread inside the thread pool instead of the main application thread.

Answer (score 2):

The answers given here will, correctly, answer your question - that is, by not awaiting the result, your call will return immediately.  However, there is no guarantee that the process will continue to run.  Once you've left the function you, effectively, have a rouge process that may or may not complete.

Most Cloud providers have a solution to this (e.g. Azure WebJobs), or you could roll your own using something like [HangFire](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire).

Comment: Hangfire indeed is worth looking at. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @kempyyyy to that extent you can look for any scheduler either Thirdparty like hangfire or Zappire (OR) there are open source library for scheduling background task in your own server

Comment: Actually eventually, the app that I'm working on would need a Job Scheduling functionality. You are on point with your suggestions. I might come back for more questions as I tackled that part. So thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Then you shouldn't `await` the call further at all and thus change the line where you await the call `RunProcessAsync` to

```
_service.RunProcessAsync(command, fileName);
```